# indexing into numpy's mgrid

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I use `numpy.mgrid` to generate "coordinate index arrays"

```
y, x = np.mgrid[0:3, 0:2]
print x
array([[0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1]])
```

In many situations, I take some slice through these arrays (e.g. `x[0, :]`) and discard the rest of the data. Sometimes, these slices are much smaller than the original arrays, which are expensive to compute (i.e. `np.mgrid[0:512, 0:512, 0:512]`). Does numpy provide an equivalent to `[coord[view] for coord in np.mgrid[0:512, 0:512, 0:512]` that doesn't generate large intermediate arrays?

I realize the solution is trivial for the slice `[0,:]`, but I'm looking for a general solution that handles any valid way to index numpy arrays

**Edit**

Some have asked for specific examples for what `view` might look like. Ideally, I'm hoping for a general solution that handles any valid way to index a ndarray. Here are a few specific examples for the 3x2 array above:

1) `view = (1, slice(None, None, 2))`

2) `view = (np.array([0,1]), np.array([0, 1]))`

3) `view = np.array([[False, False], [False, True], [False, False]])`

And I'm looking for a function like

```
def mgrid_with_view(array_shape, view)
    ...
```

That returns the equivalent of `[o[view] for o in np.indices(array_shape)]` without unnecessary computation or memory.

Comment: What is "view" in your final question?

Comment: "view" is, ideally, anything that can be used to index a numpy array. (a scalar, slice, tuples thereof, boolean or integer array, etc). For the example I provided, it would be `(0, slice(None, None, None)`

Comment: Can you give an example? I usually use np.ogrid to generate the cooridinate index arrays, and by using broadcasting, it can get the same result as np.mgrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As HYRY mentioned, I believe what you want to avoid is creating the full arrays. `mgrid` creates a full array, however if you use:

```
x, y = np.broadcast_arrays(*np.ogrid[0:2,0:3])
```

`x` and `y` take up no more memory then `np.arange(0,2)` (and `np.arange(0,3)`), while acting as if each was a full array. If you require a single large result array, you should probably slice these arrays individually and then concatenate them. (np.broadcast_arrays returns a tuple of arrays instead of an array)

Comment: Great, thank you. I guess the point here is that array broadcasting doesn't actually allocate memory to create full arrays, but rather constructs a view into another (potentially smaller) array. This lets you cheaply make large temporary arrays